# How to retrieve data from Firebase and set it as string and int for charts

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, graph

Good morning/afternoon/evening I just need help on how can I change the data of string and value from firebase to my code or chart. I'm currently using preset values as shown (String "skyobject" and int"500,300,600,123" and hoping to use data from my firebase which is shown in the image. thank you for helping me I'm new to this android studio thing so I'm grateful for any help that I can get. thank you so much in advance for those people who will help me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AnyChartView anyChartView;
    Button btn;
    DatabaseReference reff;


    String [] skyobject = {"sun","moon","stars","planets"};
    int[] datas = {500,300,600,123};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        anyChartView =( AnyChartView) findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);
        setupPieChart();


    }
    public void setupPieChart() {
        Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();
        List<DataEntry> dataEntries = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;i<skyobject.length;i++){
            dataEntries.add(new ValueDataEntry(skyobject[i],datas[i]));


        }
        pie.data(dataEntries);
        anyChartView.setChart(pie);

    }
}
```

Edited code with the given code of @Alex Mamo

```
package com.javapapers.androidchartapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.anychart.AnyChart;
import com.anychart.AnyChartView;
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.DataEntry;
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.ValueDataEntry;
import com.anychart.charts.Pie;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.javapapers.androidchartapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AnyChartView anyChartView;

    DatabaseReference rootRef;


    String [] skyobject = {"sun","moon","stars","planets"};
    int[] datas = {500,300,600,123};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = ds.getKey();
                    String name = ds.getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", key + ": " + name);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        };
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);
        setupPieChart();


    }
    public void setupPieChart() {
        Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();
        List<DataEntry> dataEntries = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;i<skyobject.length;i++){
            dataEntries.add(new ValueDataEntry(skyobject[i],datas[i]));

        }
        pie.data(dataEntries);
        anyChartView.setChart(pie);

    }
```

**This is the Error in the Logcat**

```
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.javapapers.androidchartapp, PID: 22809
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform.newAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:112)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:246)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:77)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:92)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:42)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:357)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:201)
        at com.javapapers.androidchartapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.javapapers.androidchartapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.javapapers.androidchartapp-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform.newAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:112) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.ensureAuthTokenProvider(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:246) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.initServices(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:98) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Context.freeze(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:77) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createLocalRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:92) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.RepoManager.createRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:42) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.ensureRepo(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:357) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:201) 
        at com.javapapers.androidchartapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

image of my database [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlZyz.png)

image of the pie chart output [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wZ5D.png)

edited with the given codes down there got error with the TAG [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfJOm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the keys and values for those properties, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            String name = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", key + ": " + name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
Moon: 300
Planets: 123
Stars: 600
Sun:  500
```

Comment: hello Alex I've attached a pic of my output  and I've tried the code that you've given and makes my app crash hope you can help me with this thank you

Comment: @FritzleeMagno I cannot see how the shared code is related somehow with Firebase. If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Ok @AlexMamo ill try edit it later .. i just want to get the data from firebase to use it as the data needed for the chart like the image i’ve shared (image of the final output)  cause im really having a hard time to understand thank you for your time sir

Comment: Without seeing the stack trace, I cannot be much of a help. Please leave a comment once you have added to your question.

Comment: @AlecMamo I've already added a screenshot of the error thanks for having time helping me :) im still a newbie in this stuff

Comment: I've already added a screenshot of the error thanks for having time helping me :) im still a newbie in this stuff

Comment: Does this line `Log.d("TAG", key + ": " + name);` print something? Besides that, I have never seen this `java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). ` I think you should report to the Firebase team.

Comment: nope it just crash instantly when i try to run it  @AlexMamo

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Yes thats all thats in the logcat sir @AlexMamo

Comment: Try to change `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());` into `Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());`. Does it work now?

Comment: Ive tried it  still doesnt run the app sir @AlexMamo im gonna edit the new logcat up there

Comment: uhm sir @AlexMamo it appears that i cant put it up there for it exceeds the limit text allowed

Comment: Add it to your question, not as a comment

Comment: Please add only the exception that you get and the line at which it occurs.

Comment: sir @AlexMamo ive tried to recode it from scratch and it works but it doesn't get the values from the firebase is there anything i have to change up there in the code so it will get the data from firebase instead of using the String and Int that i have typed ?

Comment: Good to hear that it finally worked. Yes, you can use a POJO class and map the result directly into an object of that class.

Comment: Okkkkk thanks for the help @AlexMamo sorry i just checked it just now i was busy yesterday :)